# How to call a C language function from x86 assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, qemu, xv6

I am recently trying to self-study OS and playing with the xv6 OS for teaching. The version I am using is the x86 one from [GitHub](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public).
What I've been doing is try to use 2-level paging when initiating the system. For that purpose, I created a page table and a page directory in main.c as follows:

```
__attribute__((__aligned__(PGSIZE)))
pde_t entrypgdir[NPDENTRIES];

__attribute__((__aligned__(PGSIZE)))
pte_t entrypgtable[NPTENTRIES];
```

Then in entry.S, I have got some assembly codes to initialize these two arrays as follows:

```
# The xv6 kernel starts executing in this file. This file is linked with
# the kernel C code, so it can refer to kernel symbols such as main().
# The boot block (bootasm.S and bootmain.c) jumps to entry below.
        
# Multiboot header, for multiboot boot loaders like GNU Grub.
# http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html
#
# Using GRUB 2, you can boot xv6 from a file stored in a
# Linux file system by copying kernel or kernelmemfs to /boot
# and then adding this menu entry:
#
# menuentry "xv6" {
#   insmod ext2
#   set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
#   set kernel='/boot/kernel'
#   echo "Loading ${kernel}..."
#   multiboot ${kernel} ${kernel}
#   boot
# }

#include "asm.h"
#include "memlayout.h"
#include "mmu.h"
#include "param.h"

# Multiboot header.  Data to direct multiboot loader.
.p2align 2
.text
.globl multiboot_header
multiboot_header:
  #define magic 0x1badb002
  #define flags 0
  .long magic
  .long flags
  .long (-magic-flags)

# By convention, the _start symbol specifies the ELF entry point.
# Since we haven't set up virtual memory yet, our entry point is
# the physical address of 'entry'.
.globl _start
_start = V2P_WO(entry)

# Entering xv6 on boot processor, with paging off.
.globl entry
entry:
  # Turn on page size extension for 4Mbyte pages
  // I comment the following to not use bigger pages
  #movl    %cr4, %eax
  #orl     $(CR4_PSE), %eax
  #movl    %eax, %cr4
  # Set page directory

  //My assembly code to initialize a page table starts
  #set up the first page table page

  xor %esi, %esi
1:
  movl %esi, %eax
  shll $12, %eax
  orl $(PTE_P|PTE_W), %eax
  movl $(V2P_WO(entrypgtable)), %edi
  movl %esi, %ebx
  shll $2, %ebx
  addl %ebx, %edi
  movl %eax, (%edi)
  incl %esi
  cmpl $1024, %esi
  jb 1b

  # Set page directory

  movl $0, %esi
  movl %esi, %ebx
  shll $2, %ebx
  movl $(V2P_WO(entrypgdir)), %edi
  addl %ebx, %edi
  movl $(V2P_WO(entrypgtable)), (%edi)
  orl $(PTE_P | PTE_W), (%edi)

  movl $512, %esi
  movl %esi, %ebx
  shll $2, %ebx
  movl $(V2P_WO(entrypgdir)), %edi
  addl %ebx, %edi
  movl $(V2P_WO(entrypgtable)), (%edi)
  orl $(PTE_P | PTE_W), (%edi)
  //My assembly code to initialize a page table ends

  movl    $(V2P_WO(entrypgdir)), %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr3
  # Turn on paging.
  movl    %cr0, %eax
  orl     $(CR0_PG|CR0_WP), %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr0

  # Set up the stack pointer.
  movl $(stack + KSTACKSIZE), %esp

  # Jump to main(), and switch to executing at
  # high addresses. The indirect call is needed because
  # the assembler produces a PC-relative instruction
  # for a direct jump.
  mov $main, %eax
  jmp *%eax

.comm stack, KSTACKSIZE
```

As you can see, the basic idea is simple: the original xv6 system uses 4mb big pages when initializing the system, so that they only need the page directory to map the kernel code to the first physical page. I disable that option and use 4kb pages, then I create a new page table accordingly, then put the new page table into the page directory array.
If my understanding is correct, the whole process should be equivalent to the following C code:

```
__attribute__((__aligned__(PGSIZE)))
pde_t entrypgdir[NPDENTRIES];

__attribute__((__aligned__(PGSIZE)))
pte_t entrypgtable[NPTENTRIES];

void init_entrypgdir(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NPTENTRIES; i++) {
        entrypgtable[i] = (i << 12) | PTE_P | PTE_W;
    }
    entrypgdir[0] = (uint)(V2P_WO(entrypgtable)) | PTE_P | PTE_W;
    entrypgdir[KERNBASE>>PDXSHIFT] = (uint)(V2P_WO(entrypgtable)) | PTE_P | PTE_W;
}
```

The above code resides in main.c, which is linked together with entry.S. I have confirmed that entry.S has access to my newly created init_entrypgdir() function.

Now comes the problem: what if I want to get rid of self-written assembly code and use the above C code to initialize xv6? Is there a way to replace my assembly code with my C code and still successfully initialize the OS?

I have tried to rewrite entry.S as:

```
#include "asm.h"
#include "memlayout.h"
#include "mmu.h"
#include "param.h"

# Multiboot header.  Data to direct multiboot loader.
.p2align 2
.text
.globl multiboot_header
multiboot_header:
  #define magic 0x1badb002
  #define flags 0
  .long magic
  .long flags
  .long (-magic-flags)

# By convention, the _start symbol specifies the ELF entry point.
# Since we haven't set up virtual memory yet, our entry point is
# the physical address of 'entry'.
.globl _start
_start = V2P_WO(entry)

# Entering xv6 on boot processor, with paging off.
.globl entry
entry:
  # Turn on page size extension for 4Mbyte pages
  // I comment the following to not use bigger pages
  #movl    %cr4, %eax
  #orl     $(CR4_PSE), %eax
  #movl    %eax, %cr4

  // see if this works
  call V2P_WO(init_entrypgdir)

  # Set page directory
  movl    $(V2P_WO(entrypgdir)), %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr3
  # Turn on paging.
  movl    %cr0, %eax
  orl     $(CR0_PG|CR0_WP), %eax
  movl    %eax, %cr0

  # Set up the stack pointer.
  movl $(stack + KSTACKSIZE), %esp

  # Jump to main(), and switch to executing at
  # high addresses. The indirect call is needed because
  # the assembler produces a PC-relative instruction
  # for a direct jump.
  mov $main, %eax
  jmp *%eax

.comm stack, KSTACKSIZE
```

Then, in GDB, I created breakpoints at lines 108, 110, and 112.
[image]

[image]

As you can see on the screenshots, breakpoint 112 never gets hit, and qemu monitor freezes like this
[image]

I wonder why line 112 is never run? Is there anything wrong with my for loop?

Comment: At the very least, use qemu monitor to figure out what the "freeze" really means and what the machine state is. Also instead of the working code provide the non-working as a [mcve] if that's what you need help with.

Comment: Just calling the function should definitely work.  What happened when you ran this under a debugger?